# Creating a common method for Capistrano tasks

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Let's say in my standard `deploy.rb` file I have a set of namespaces. I have a common task that lists RPM packages based on a variable I pass to it. When I run this as is, it complains about `capture` being an undefined method. If I include that method inside the `deploy.rb` file, it works just fine.

Mind you, I'm new to ruby and to OOP so I'm sure I'm doing this the wrong way. :-)

## deploy.rb

```
load 'config/module'

namespace :lp_app do
desc "LP tasks"

co = Tasks::Commands.new()

    task :list do
        co.list_pkg("LP")
    end
end
```

## module.rb

```
module Tasks
    class Commands
        def list_pkg(component)
            File.open("#{component}.file.list", "r").each_line do |line|
                pkg_name = "#{line}".chomp

                set :server_pkg, capture("rpm -q #{pkg_name}")

                puts "#{server_pkg}"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Capistano specific commands outside of Capistrano.  If you want to set a variable to the result of something you run on the command line, try the backtick (`).

```
module Tasks
    class Commands
        def list_pkg(component)
            File.open("#{component}.file.list", "r").each_line do |line|
                pkg_name = "#{line}".chomp

                server_pkg = `rpm -q #{pkg_name}`

                puts server_pkg
            end
        end
    end
end
```